# Deploying Shiny with ramazon on AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I've followed this tutorial: [Link](https://andreacirilloblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/deploy-your-shiny-app-on-aws-with-a-function/) to set up an shiny app on a EC2 AWS instance.

For my first attempt, I am using a simple shiny app. Code below:

```
library(shiny)

# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've saved the script as an app.R and placed the key pair in the same directory as the script.

Once I run the ramazon function I get:

```
WELL DONE!
YOU CAN FIND YOUR SHINY APP AT THE FOLLOWING URL:
35.177.231.89:3838/aws_shiny
Warning messages:
1: running command 'chmod 400 C:/Users/Bobi/Documents/aws_shiny/myname.pem' had status 127 
2: running command 'chmod 700 bash_script.sh' had status 127 
3: running command 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v -i C:/Users/Bobi/Documents/aws_shiny/myname.pem ubuntu@35.177.231.89 'bash -s' < bash_script.sh' had status 127 
4: running command 'exit' had status 127 
5: running command 'scp -v -i C:/Users/Bobi/Documents/aws_shiny/myname.pem -r C:/Users/Bobi/Documents/aws_shiny ubuntu@35.177.231.89:/srv/shiny-server/' had status 127
```

Any ideas what the status 127 means?

Comment: I believe exit status `127` means "command not found". The tutorial you linked to shows the creation of an Ubuntu EC2 instance. Your paths look like DOS/Windows paths. Those commands the process is trying to run, especially `chmod`, are Linux commands. Did you create a Windows server instead of a Linux server?

Comment: No, I created: Canonical, Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS. :S

Comment: I guess those commands are running on your local machine, not on the AWS server? That seems to be the case now that I look at what the commands are doing. Maybe the tutorial doesn't work for Windows users. You could try running everything in the Windows Subsystem for Linux https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: @MarkB you were right. It works on Linux. Thank you!

Comment: Just FYI: There is a very quick way to setup r/shiny on aws: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/. It requires only a few clicks on aws with the help of the great AMI. Maybe it is of interest for you as well,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist this is awesome. I've read earlier about the AMI, but I wasn't aware that it contained shiny as well!

Comment: @BigDataScientist hi, could you please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614021/shinyapps-on-aws-with-rstudio-ami

Comment: hi, sry i was without internet a few days. I try to take a look later!

Comment: Thats more server side related. Fredric Henri might be able to help there,..

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive blog post [Running R on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/) available in Amazon Big Data Blog which will guide you through installing and running R, RStudio Server, and Shiny Server on AWS.