# ShinyApps on AWS with Rstudio AMI

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I created an AWS instance with this [R Studio AMI](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/).

The instructions point that to make the Shiny App available to public you should put it in a ShinyApps folder (public dir).

The issue I'm having though, is that my apps are accesable only through that particular directory, but I can't access them through subdirectories.

For instance:

```
http://<instance IP address>/shiny/username - works
http://<instance IP address>/shiny/**subdirectory**/username - doesnt work
```

So I can't really show more than one Shiny App on a single instance.

My goal is to create an index.html page that links several ShinyApps like [this one](http://ec2-54-251-191-252.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com).

**Update**:

I've updated my index.html with this [repo](https://github.com/ndow-wisr/ndow-data)

The problem is again, when I link an app from the index.html I get only the R code opens up, rather than the app.